# Relationship between integral of a function and integral of square of function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, gamma-function, bessel-functions

Is there a relationship between the results of $$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$$ and $$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)^2dx$$
if $f$ is positive definite?

EDIT: I'm adding more details concerning the specific functions i'm dealing with.
So far I have found $$\int_{0}^\infty \omega^\alpha K_\nu\left(\omega\right)d\omega = 2^{\alpha-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1-\nu}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1+\nu}{2}\right)$$
with $\alpha=0, \frac12, 1, \frac32 ,...$ and $\nu=0, \frac12, 1$, and $K_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of 2nd kind.

I would like to find $$\int_{0}^\infty (\omega^\alpha K_\nu(\omega))^2d\omega$$

Comment: $f$ is a linear map?

Comment: One has the square and the other not:)

Comment: Yes. It actually is a product of a polynomial with a decreasing exponential, or with a bessel function.

Comment: @GuyFsone so you mean there's no simple relationship between the results of each?

Comment: In fact your question has to be precise otherwise it might closed as too broad

Comment: @GuyFsone if it's too broad as there is no general relationship (with the positive definite condition), then that's already an answer. I'm not sure how to get it more precise, or should I state an example?

Comment: the problem in the question is that $f$ is too general to make good answers, put some more assumptions

Comment: Ok i must run now but will add full details in a couple of hours or so

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be $d\omega$ instead of $dx$? How is $K_\nu$ defined? But I don't think it make a difference. Normally you can't really compare the integrals, espially if you need the explicit values. If $\omega^\alpha K_\nu(\omega)\leq 1$ for all $\omega\geq 0$, then you could just say $\int_0^\infty(\omega^\alpha K_\nu(\omega))^2~d\omega\leq \int_0^\infty \omega^\alpha K_\nu(\omega)~d\omega$.

Comment: Yes you are right i was distracted, corrected now. $K_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we talk about Lebesgue-integrals, we can consider
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx=\int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)\leq 1\}}f(x)~dx+
\int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)> 1\}}f(x)~dx.
$$
So you see
$$
\int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)\leq 1\}}f(x)~dx\geq \int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)\leq 1\}}f^2(x)~dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)> 1\}}f(x)~dx\leq \int_{\{x\geq 0~:~f(x)> 1\}}f^2(x)~dx.
$$
So you can't really compare the integrals because the inequality are different. Moreover consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ defined by 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{n^{3/4}} & x\leq n\\0 & x>n
\end{cases}
$$
Then you get $$
\int_0^\infty f_n(x)~dx=n^{1/4}\to\infty\text{ for }n\to\infty
$$
while
$$
\int_0^\infty f_n^2(x)~dx=n^{-1/2}\to0\text{ for }n\to\infty
$$
But you can also do it the other way. Define
$$
g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n^{3/4} & x\leq \frac1n\\ 0 & x>\frac1n
\end{cases}.
$$
Then you get $$
\int_0^\infty g_n(x)~dx=n^{-1/4}\to 0\text{ for }n\to\infty
$$
while
$$
\int_0^\infty g_n^2(x)~dx=n^{1/2}\to\infty\text{ for }n\to\infty
$$
So you see that there is no simple relation between $\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx$ and $\int_0^\infty f^2(x)~dx$.

You get go even further. For $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x & x>0\\0 & x=0\end{cases}
$$
you get $\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx=\infty$ while $\int_0^\infty f^2(x)~dx=1$ and for
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\sqrt{x}} & x\leq 1\\0 & x>1\end{cases}
$$
you get $\int_0^\infty g(x)~dx=\frac23$ while $\int_0^\infty g^2(x)~dx=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you Mundron, so there is no general relationship. I'll be adding more details though as suggested in the comments, maybe there is something to say in my precise case.

Answer (score 1):

If a function can be described by a Taylor series, then the indefinite integral will be dominated by only the nth terms. Therefore, the square of the function will be dominated by the square of the nth terms. My intuition is, then, that the ratio of the indefinite integrals of the square of the function to the function itself are approximately a_n*(n+1)*x^n/(2n+1).

Answer (score 0):

If some wonder, i found the solution to my integral, with no obvious relation to the one of the function not squared :)

$$\int_{0}^\infty (\omega^\alpha K_\nu(\omega))^2d\omega = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2-\nu) \Gamma(\alpha+1/2)\Gamma(\alpha+1/2+\nu)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}$$